# Westend Bond TX failed with unclear reason

Tags: polkadot, westend

Would you please help me to understand why failed my bond tX
https://westend.subscan.io/extrinsic/0x70e6193b601e5e0f96cb201f5d0ead98ee752fa1a024b6b2462d7f80a8415032

My extrinsic:

```
signedExtrinsic {
  isSigned: true,
  method: {
    args: { value: '2,900,000,000,000', payee: [Object] },
    method: 'bond',
    section: 'staking'
  },
  era: { MortalEra: { period: '64', phase: '36' } },
  nonce: '83',
  signature: '0x0e9e9b35e7f12f6b0bfdc8f8ff72929fbf1ae141e1f03c2d5c84f85c1883b743747ecb793a143587ab7f585fc958d8cd9aa4b1ce0c315714a8ffce565bd5bf86',
  signer: { Id: '5D4xskDvK3nCnkGthhuaizkTWVPx3kG7q6nea5XPNMhf2Jhf' },
  tip: '0'
}
signedExtrinsic toHex 0x490284002c6eca5cdaa3e87d7f8e06d10015bf0508b52d301c8991af113d5cf49a53553f010e9e9b35e7f12f6b0bfdc8f8ff72929fbf1ae141e1f03c2d5c84f85c1883b743747ecb793a143587ab7f585fc958d8cd9aa4b1ce0c315714a8ffce565bd5bf8645024d010006000b00487835a302034e8ee510bba056e20a4ab84439694ad6ad4f38d4485de8faf62f2e465b49df06
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's check the Subscan link, here you can confirm that the ExtrinsicFailed and display more information about it:
[image]

We can see the dispatch_error that has a index 6 and an error 0x02000000.
To understand this we have to take a look into the code of Substrate.

The `index` number is the index of the pallet in the runtime from which the error originated. The `error` is  the index of that pallet's errors (Both of these indices start counting from 0).

So let's check first which is the pallet with index 6 in the Westend runtime code([see link here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/polkadot/runtime/westend/src/lib.rs#L1380C12-L1380C26)).

```rs
construct_runtime! {
    pub enum Runtime
    {
      ...
      Staking: pallet_staking::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Config<T>, Event<T>} = 6,
      ...
}
```

We see the error originated in the pallet staking, we go into `pallet_staking` code to find out what is the error. `0x02000000` is 2 in hex: ([See the link to the code here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/substrate/frame/staking/src/pallet/mod.rs#L794C3-L795C1))

```rs
#[pallet::error]
    pub enum Error<T> {
    ...
     /// Stash is already bonded.
     AlreadyBonded,
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! AlreadyBonded is because 0x02000000 ===2 and it is an index in [:pallet] https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/substrate/frame/staking/src/pallet/mod.rs#L787 ?

Comment: Yes, this is the index of the error